# Method returning varying types of object

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-volley, gson

I am making http get requests using gson and volley. My idea was to have a method return an object containing serialised JSON.

```
public responseHolder getRequest(){
    //Make call
    //Parse Json into JsonObject
    return responseHolder;
}
```

My problem is that I want the method work with different api calls returning different data. I have 3 classes designed to store 3 different calls and I want the method to return the correct type of object. Is there a method or design pattern that would help me in this scenario or should I approach it from a different angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```
private String getRequest()
{
    // Make Call
    return jsonString;
}

public TypeA getA()
{
    return new Gson().fromJson(getRequest(), TypeA.class);
}

public TypeB getB()
{
    return new Gson().fromJson(getRequest(), TypeB.class);
}

public TypeC getC()
{
    return new Gson().fromJson(getRequest(), TypeC.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public <T> T getRequest(Class<T> clazz){
    //Make call
    //Parse Json into JsonObject
    String json = ...;
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a superclass of the three response classes.

```
public class Response { ... }
public class ResponseSubClass0 extends Response{ ... }
public class ResponseSubClass1 extends Response{ ... }
public class ResponseSubClass2 extends Response{ ... }
```

Then just define your method as returning Response.

```
public Response getResponse(){
    //do stuff
    return response; //can be any of the subclass types
}
```

In whatever code block is using `getResponse()` you can use use `typeof` to check which one it is if you need the specifics of a particular class.

```
Response r = foo.getResponse();
if(r instanceof ResponseSubClass0){
    ResponseSubClass0 rsc0 = (ResponseSubClass0)r;
    //do stuff
}
else if(r instanceof ResponseSubClass1){
    ResponseSubClass1 rsc1 = (ResponseSubClass1)r;
    //do other stuff
}
else if(r instanceof ResponseSubClass2){
    ResponseSubClass2 rsc2 = (ResponseSubClass2)r;
    //do other stuff
}
```

You could also make Response an interface and implement it instead of extending a superclass.